# HttpClient returns 0 bytes

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient

`GetByteArrayAsync` and `GetStreamAsync` both returns 0 bytes or empty stream. I want to write the bytes received to a file.

I have tried using `byte[] stream = await _httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync("http://gscs-b2c.lge.com/downloadFile?fileId=BZhqND5RTnHcyMRDCeJJQ")` and `_httpClient.GetStreamAsync("http://gscs-b2c.lge.com/downloadFile?fileId=BZhqND5RTnHcyMRDCeJJQ")`, but both of them return either 0 bytes or empty stream.

I have tried from PostMan, as a Get request, it returned a valid PDF file. I have tried it from the browser, it returns a valid PDF file. But here in the code it return empty file (0 bytes). I checked other answers but still I could not fix this. Interestingly it works for other pdf files from other sites.

Following is the sample code in .net Core 2.2 that I am using

```
_client = new HttpClient();
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36");
_client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

var downloadPdfLink = "http://gscs-b2c.lge.com/downloadFile?fileId=BZhqND5RTnHcyMRDCeJJQ";
using (Stream stream = await _client.GetStreamAsync(downloadPdfLink))
{
    using (var fs = new FileStream("./file/myfile.pdf",FileMode.CreateNew,FileAccess.Write))
    {
        //stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        stream.CopyTo(fs);
    }
}
```

The expected result should be that the returned stream is written to "myfile.pdf". Can you please help me understand what is the problem here, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When downloading the `.pdf` file via a web browser, I have noticed in the *Developer Tools* that additional Headers get added to the Request:
`Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate`, amongst others, which will in return carry the file in the Content of the Response, rather than leaving it with a Length of 0 like in your original code.

There are several ways in fixing your code:

#### [HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.defaultrequestheaders)

```cs
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "deflate");
```

#### [HttpClientHandler.AutomaticDecompression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.automaticdecompression)

```cs
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
var _client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

#### [HttpRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httprequestheaders.acceptencoding)

```cs
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, downloadPdfLink);
request.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
request.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("deflate"));
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.SendAsync(request))
{
    using (Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory("./file");
        using (var fs = new FileStream("./file/myfile.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            //stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            stream.CopyTo(fs);
        }
    }
}
```

And, as a friendly reminder, don't forget to `Dispose()` your `HttpClient`, once you are done with it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't understand how I missed looking at that!!. Yes this works perfectly. 

Regarding calling Dispose() method, this was a sample code, otherwise I was using it as DI, using IServiceCollection.AddHttpService(). But I appreciate for the thorough review.

Comment: Disposing of the HttpClient causes problems, because you're not actually disposing of it (at least not in the same sense as other objects). Reusing HttpClient is the best aproach. More info -> https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/